# Simple Parse in Haskell with do construct

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a simple Parser, so all the declarations are listed in the image below, but when I try to compile this module it fails.
I'm following the tutorial provided by this source ->
[Haskell lessons suggested by official site](https://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/haskell?page=2) and specifically this video by Dr. Erik Meijer ([Lesson on Parser with "do" construct](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Erik-Meijer-Functional-Programming-Fundamentals/C9-Lectures-Dr-Erik-Meijer-Functional-Programming-Fundamentals-Chapter-8-of-13)).

The problem is that I thought that the "do" construct was able to "concatenate" outputs from a previous function in a descending way, but the way that this p function should work seems to be magic to me. What's the right implementation?

```
-- Generic Parser.
type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]

-- A simple Parser that captures the first char of the string, puts it in
-- the first position of the couple and then puts the rest of the string into
-- the second place of the couple inside the singleton list.
item :: Parser Char
item = \inp -> case inp of
    [] -> []
(x:xs) -> [(x, xs)]

-- Simple parser that always fails.    
failure :: Parser a
failure = \inp -> []

-- Returns the type of the parser without operating on the input.
return1 :: a -> Parser a
return1 v = \inp -> [(v, inp)]

-- Explicit call to parse.
parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
parse p inp = p inp

-- Some kind of "or" operator that if the first parser fails (returning an empty list) it
-- parses the second parser.
(+++) :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a
p +++ q = \inp -> case p inp of
    [] -> parse q inp
    [(v, out)] -> [(v, out)]

-- The function within I'm having troubles.
p :: Parser (Char,Char)
p = do
    x <- item
    item
    y <- item
    return1 (x, y)
```

[image]

This is how it's explained by Dr. Meijer:
[image]

And this is how it should work:
[image]

Comment: Where is your `Monad` instance for `Parser`?

Comment: Your `p` is making use of the `(->) String` monad, not any kind of `Parser` monad. You need to make `Parser` a `newtype`, and then write the `Monad` instance for it before you can use `do` as you want.

Comment: @n.m. Sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: Never paste images of text! Copy and paste, or type out. The image is useless for blind users and annoying for all other users.

Comment: I can't understand why this is being downvoted. Images should be replaced, I concur -- but at least this question shows some effort, unlike many others by people who are learning Haskell.

Comment: I think Erik Meijer is playing fast and loose in his talk. You cannot really make `Parser` an instance of `Monad` in a way that makes monadic parsing work. The problem is, `String ->` **is** an instance of `Monad` (so the do notation works), but it's a wrong instance and produces all the wrong types.Try to rewrite this function using an explicit `bind` rather than `do`. Alternatively you can wrap `Parser` in a newtype like this `newtype Parser a = Parser { unparser :: String -> [(a, String)] }` and define a Monad instance for that... but that's probably too much for the first Monad lesson...

Answer (score 4):

Your `Parser` is just a type synonym for a function. The friendly parsers you've seen in use are all proper types of their own, with `Functor` and `Applicative` instances, along with (in most cases) `Alternative`, `Monad`, and `MonadPlus` instances. You probably want something that looks like the following (untested, never compiled) version.

```
import Control.Monad (ap, liftM)
import Control.Applicative (Alternative (..))

newtype Parser a = Parser
  { runParser :: String -> [(a, String)] }

instance Functor Parser where
  fmap = liftM

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure v = Parser $ \inp -> [(v, inp)]
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad Parser where
  -- The next line isn't required for
  -- recent GHC versions
  -- return = pure

  Parser m >>= f = Parser $ \s ->
    [(r, s'') | (x, s') <- m s
              , (r, s'') <- runParser (f r) s']

(+++) :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a
p +++ q = Parser $ \inp -> case runParser p inp of
  [] -> runParser q inp
  [(v, out)] -> [(v, out)]

failure :: Parser a
failure = Parser $ \inp -> []

instance Alternative Parser where
  (<|>) = (+++)
  empty = failure

instance MonadPlus Parser
```